# How can i control the number of tries for the user & have it store in an array & display the array in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

This is quite a lengthy code, but i wish to have the user put in her inputs but is limited to 5 tries. Each time she enters a wrong number, it is being stored into an array. At the end of her 5 tries, all her guesses will be displayed in the text area that is created. Idk why my loop isn't working & i'm currently am unsure of loops for javascript. Help would be appreciated :) Run the code would help you better understand what I mean!

```js
var randomNo;
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) 
{
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min; 
}

function playFunction() 
{ 
  const message1 = document.getElementById("wrongInput");
  const message2 = document.getElementById("wrongInput2");
  var min = Number(document.getElementById("input").value);
  var max = Number(document.getElementById("input2").value);        

  function inIt()
  {
    message2.innerHTML = ""; 
    message1.innerHTML = ""; 
  }

  function validateInput(displayErrorElement, value)
  {
    let message; 

    if (value = "")
    {
      message = "empty"; 
    } else if (isNaN(value))
    { 
      message = "not a number"; 
    } 

    if (message) 
    {
    displayErrorElement.innerHTML = "Input is " + message; 
    displayErrorElement.style.color = "red"; 

    return false;
    }

    return true; 
  }

  function validateRange(displayErrorElement, min, max) 
  {
    if (min > max) 
    {
      displayErrorElement.innerHTML = "The input must be higher than the lowest number";

      return false; 
    } 

    return true; 
  }

  inIt();
  if(!validateInput(message1, min)) return false; 
  if(!validateInput(message2, max)) return false;
  if(!validateRange(message2, min, max)) return false; 

  console.log(min);
  console.log(max);
  randomNo = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(max, min));
  console.log(randomNo);
  console.log(randomNo);
}

values = []; 
function guess() 
{
  var maxGuesses = 5; 
  var x;
  var target;

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
  { 
    var guess = document.getElementById("guessField").value; 
    //output the msg
    var output = document.getElementById("output");

    if (guess == randomNo) 
    { 
      output.value = "You have guessed correctly! " + "(" + guess + ")";
      return true; 
    }

    else if (guess > randomNo) 
    {
      output.value = "Number is too high! " + "(" + guess + ")";
      return false; 
    } else { 
      output.value = "Number is too low! " + "(" + guess + ")";
      return false; 
    } 

    if (x == 4)
    {
      output.value = "You have run out of tries!"
    }

    target = document.getElementById("output"); 
    target.innerHTML = "The target number is " + randomNo; 
    x = document.getElementById("guessField"); 
    values.push(x.value); 
    x.value = ""; 
  }

}

function displayRecord()
{
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = values.join("<br>");
}
```

```html
Enter a smaller number<br>
<input id="input" type="text">
<span id="wrongInput"></span><br>

Enter a larger number<br>
<input id="input2" type="text">
<span id="wrongInput2"></span><br>
<button type="button" onclick="playFunction()">Play button</button>
<br>


<!-- guess the number -->
<label for="guess">Guess the number</label><br>
<input text="text" class="guessField" id="guessField">
<span id="guessMessage"></span>
<input type="button" onclick="guess()" value="Guess button"><br>
<p>Output area</p>
<textarea id="output" name="output" rows="5" style="width: 50%"></textarea>
```

Comment: Separate the steps mentioned in your "question" and find the one that doesn't work as expected. Then try to isolate the exact problem. A [mcve] will help you to find the source of the problem.

Comment: The `guess` function should not have a loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp then how can I stop @ 5?

Answer (score 0):

The `guess` function should not have a loop. Since you add the guess to the  `values` array, you can use that to keep track of how many guesses have been made and quit the game when `values.length == 5;`

Also note I append the messages with `+=`. Example `output.value += "You ....`

```js
let values = []; 
var randomNo;
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) 
{
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min; 
}

function playFunction() 
{ 
  const message1 = document.getElementById("wrongInput");
  const message2 = document.getElementById("wrongInput2");
  var min = Number(document.getElementById("input").value);
  var max = Number(document.getElementById("input2").value);        

  function inIt()
  {
    message2.innerHTML = ""; 
    message1.innerHTML = ""; 
    values = []; 
    document.getElementById("output").value = "";
  }

  function validateInput(displayErrorElement, value)
  {
    let message; 

    if (value = "")
    {
      message = "empty"; 
    } else if (isNaN(value))
    { 
      message = "not a number"; 
    } 

    if (message) 
    {
    displayErrorElement.innerHTML = "Input is " + message; 
    displayErrorElement.style.color = "red"; 

    return false;
    }

    return true; 
  }

  function validateRange(displayErrorElement, min, max) 
  {
    if (min > max) 
    {
      displayErrorElement.innerHTML = "The input must be higher than the lowest number";

      return false; 
    } 

    return true; 
  }

  inIt();
  if(!validateInput(message1, min)) return false; 
  if(!validateInput(message2, max)) return false;
  if(!validateRange(message2, min, max)) return false; 

  console.log(min);
  console.log(max);
  randomNo = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(max, min));
  console.log(randomNo);
  console.log(randomNo);
}

function guess() 
{
    var maxGuesses = 5;

    if (values.length >= maxGuesses) return false;

    var guess = document.getElementById("guessField").value; 
    document.getElementById("guessField").value = "";
    values.push(guess);
    //output the msg
    var output = document.getElementById("output");

    if (guess == randomNo) { 
        output.value += "You have guessed correctly! (" + guess + ")\n";
        return true; 
    }
    if (guess > randomNo) 
    {
        output.value += "Number is too high! (" + guess + ")\n";
    }
    else { 
        output.value += "Number is too low! (" + guess + ")\n";
    } 

    if (values.length == 5)
    {
        output.value += "You have run out of tries!\n"
        output.value += "The target number is " + randomNo;
    }
}

function displayRecord()
{
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = values.join("<br>");
}
```

```html
Enter a smaller number<br>
<input id="input" type="text">
<span id="wrongInput"></span><br>

Enter a larger number<br>
<input id="input2" type="text">
<span id="wrongInput2"></span><br>
<button type="button" onclick="playFunction()">Play button</button>
<br>


<!-- guess the number -->
<label for="guess">Guess the number</label><br>
<input text="text" class="guessField" id="guessField">
<span id="guessMessage"></span>
<input type="button" onclick="guess()" value="Guess button"><br>
<p>Output area</p>
<textarea id="output" name="output" rows="5" style="width: 50%"></textarea>
```